# How do I determine what CSS framework version is being used in divshot?

Tags: divshot

I'm glad to see that ZURB's Foundation is in the list. I'd like to use Foundation 4 for this next project; what version is being used currently?

Is there a way to link to it (via "Custom") if it's < 4?

Comment: I would also like to know this good question

Answer (score 0):

Divshot supports the following framework versions:

- Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.1
- ZURB Foundation 4.0.9
- Ratchet 1.0.0

If a new major version is released (such as Bootstrap 3) we'll provide backward compatibility. You'll be able to use both Bootstrap 3 and the legacy version.

At the moment there's no way to see the current version within Divshot unless you examine the framework's CSS files. The version should be visible at the top. We'll expose this data in a future update to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the project name just above the Navigator in the upper left corner of the screen. This will take you to your projects page. Hover your cursor over the project in question, and click on the gear icon (project settings). Here you will be able to see which framework is selected for the project.